# Textboxes binded to SelectedItem of a code-behind created DataGrid don't actualize

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm experimenting with code-behind created WPF masks as prototype for a WPF mask designer.
In my ViewModel i have a DataTable and a DataView (which is simply the DefaultView of the DataTable).
In my DataTable i got two columns ("vorname" and "nachname") and four rows.
In my WPF mask i want to have a DataGrid and two TextBoxes, which are binded to the SelectedItem of the DataGrid and the columns (either "vorname" or "nachname").
When i select an item in the DatGrid at runtime, the data from that item shall be showed in the TextBoxes.

First i tried to define the DataGrid in the XAML file and generate the TextBoxes an their bindings in code.
Here it works fine.
I select an item in the DataGrid and the data of the item is showed in the TextBoxes.

But when i generate the grid in code, it doesn't work anymore.
Is there some sort of NotifyOnSelectedIndexChanged, that i'm missing?

Any help will be appreciated.

This is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DesignerTest.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TestWindow"
        Height="400"
        Width="600">
    <DockPanel x:Name="mainpanel">
        <!--<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid"
                  DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                  Height="120" />-->
        <WrapPanel x:Name="wrappanel">
            <!--<TextBox x:Name="vornameSelected" Width="150" Margin="5" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.vorname, ElementName=datagrid}" IsEnabled="False" />
            <TextBox x:Name="nachnameSelected" Width="150" Margin="5" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.nachname, ElementName=datagrid}" IsEnabled="False" />-->
            <!--<TextBox x:Name="vornameSelected" Width="150" Margin="5" IsEnabled="False" />
            <TextBox x:Name="nachnameSelected" Width="150" Margin="5" IsEnabled="False" />-->
        </WrapPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And this is the code for creating and binding:

```
    // The ViewModel und the DataTable are created.
    _vm = new SerializingTestViewModel();
    _vm.CreateDataTable();
    this.DataContext = _vm.DataTable;

    // The DataGrid  and it's Binding are created.
    DataGrid datagrid = new DataGrid();
    datagrid.Name = "datagrid";
    DockPanel.SetDock(datagrid, Dock.Top);
    datagrid.Height = 120;
    datagrid.ItemsSource = _vm.DataSource;
    mainpanel.Children.Add(datagrid);

    // The Textboxes and the Bindings are created.
    TextBox vornameSelected = new TextBox();
    vornameSelected.Name = "vornameSelected";
    vornameSelected.Width = 150;
    Thickness margin = new Thickness(5);
    vornameSelected.SetValue(TextBox.MarginProperty, margin);
    vornameSelected.IsEnabled = false;
    Binding selectedItemBinding = new Binding();
    selectedItemBinding.ElementName = "datagrid";
    selectedItemBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem.vorname");
    vornameSelected.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, selectedItemBinding);
    wrappanel.Children.Add(vornameSelected);

    TextBox nachnameSelected = new TextBox();
    nachnameSelected.Name = "nachnameSelected";
    nachnameSelected.Width = 150;
    margin = new Thickness(5);
    nachnameSelected.SetValue(TextBox.MarginProperty, margin);
    nachnameSelected.IsEnabled = false;
    selectedItemBinding = new Binding();
    selectedItemBinding.ElementName = "datagrid";
    selectedItemBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem.nachname");
    nachnameSelected.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, selectedItemBinding);
    wrappanel.Children.Add(nachnameSelected);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "mask"?

Comment: Try adding a trace to the bindings and see what you get in the VS output pane: `System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.SetTraceLevel(selectedItemBinding, System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceLevel.High);` I've only used that in XAML, but it's an attached property so it should work just like that (he said, optimistically).

Comment: With "mask" i mean a WPF window. Sorry.

Comment: Does it work if you set your `selectedItemBinding.Source = datagrid;` rather than setting `selectedItemBinding.ElementName = "datagrid"`? The problem might be that the ElementName lookup for items is not working correctly due to the items being added via code behind.

Comment: Sorry Rachel, but even by Setting the Source property, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry again Rachel.
You are absolutely right, but i didn't recognized it.
When creating the DataGrid in code-behind and binding TextBoxes to the SelectedItem property, we have to set the instance of the DataGrid in the Source property of the TextBoxes.

Comment: @PatrickPirzer Good to hear :) I posted that comment as an Answer in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your binding source using the `Source` property instead of `ElementName`

```
//selectedItemBinding.ElementName = "datagrid"
selectedItemBinding.Source = datagrid;
```

The problem might be that the `ElementName` lookup for items is not working as expected because items are added dynamically at runtime via code behind.